# How to use spacing here?

Tags: openframeworks

```
int spacing = 50; 
ofBeginShape（）; 

for（int x = 0; x < ofGetWidth（）; x + = spacing）{ 
  ofCurveVertex（x，ofGetHeight（）/ 2 + ofGetHeight（）* 0.3f * sin（x * 0.01f + ofGetFrameNum（）* 0.02f）） ; 
  } 
  ofEndShape（false）;
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. To get a good response to your question it will be helpful to describe your problem in some detail rather than simply pasting some code. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [formatting tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to help improve your post.

Answer (score 0):

> `x + = spacing`

in your for-loop, `+=` is a single operator (increment), and should be used without spacing